# gnuplot gsl compiling linking

Tags: compilation, gsl

I would like to use the gsl library.
When I compile the .c code I have this error:

```
(base) alexandre@alexandre-Latitude-E7270:~/gsl-2.6$ qcc -O2 -Wall gsl.c -o gnu -lm
gsl.c:2:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No files or folders of this type
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And I have follow the Installation Instructions. Then :

```
./configure CC=c99 CFLAGS=-g LIBS=-lposix
```

What else do I need to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,
I was getting that mistake because I didn't have it installed :

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

Now it works